# scrollTop returns 0

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a fixed div in a vuejs app that i intend to use as a chat box. The div scrolls it's content within itself. I try to scroll to bottom automatically once chat box is open but it never works.

I have tried to assign scrollHeight to scrollTop but scrollTop always returns 0 even after assignment.
I have also emitted an event to the parent component that contains the scrollBar of the chat window to try to scroll but the problem is the same. scrollTop never gets assigned.

```js
let msg = document.querySelector(".messanger .messanger-body");
msg.scrollTop = msg.scrollHeight;
console.log(msg.scrollTop);
console.log(msg.scrollHeight);
```

My problem is msg.scrollTop never gets assigned what msg.scrollHeight is. It remains 0.

```html
<div class="messanger">
  <div class="messanger-header text-center">
    <div class="row h-100">
      <div class="col-sm-12 my-auto">
        <h2 class="ml-2 text-white">Chat</h2>
        <div class="float-left">
          <base-button size="sm" class="ml-1" type="primary" @click="returnToPrev">&larr;</base-button>
        </div>
        <div class="float-right">
          <base-button size="sm" class="mr-1" type="primary">Send message</base-button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="messanger-body">
    <div>
      <!-- child component -->
      <message-thread :user="msgThread.user" @scrolltobtm="scrollViewToBtm"></message-thread>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a CSS like so for the parent component

```css
.messanger {
  background: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 310px;
  height: 70vh;
  float: right;
  right: 10px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin-top: 20vh;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.messanger .messanger-header {
  position: fixed;
  height: 60px !important;
  width: 310px !important;
  background: #25457a;
  color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 99999;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
}
.messanger .messanger-body {
  margin-top: 65px;
}
```

For my child component i have

```html
    <div class="message-history mt-2">
      <div class="message-history-content">
        <div class="text-center mb-4">
          <span class="badge badge-info">Thread title : {{threadTitle}}</span>
        </div>
        <div v-for="(eachMessage, index) in messages" :key="index">
          <div :class="messagePosition(eachMessage.added_by)[0]"> 
            <!-- classes msg_container and msg_container_send are dynamically added here -->
            <span>{{eachMessage.message}}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="message-input">
        <form class="form m-1" @submit.prevent="sendMessage">
          <textarea v-model="model.message" class="form-control"></textarea>
          <div>
            <button class="ni ni-send"></button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Child component css

```css
.msg_container {
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #82ccdd;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.msg_container_send {
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-right: 20%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #25457a;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.message-input {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: calc(100% - 90%);
  background: #ffffff;
  z-index: 99999;
}
.message-history {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.message-history .message-history-content {
  overflow: scroll;
}
form {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
}
form button.ni.ni-send {
  margin-top: 3px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  height: 34px;
  width: 34px;
  background: #25457a;
  color: #ffffff;
}
textarea {
  flex-grow: 1;
  resize: none;
  border: 1px solid #25457a;
}
form button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
```

Thank you for help in advance.
I added overflow property to the .message-history class, it still doesn't work. I believe my mistake resides in my styles. I'm not much of a CSS person.
The chat window scrolls when the mouse is used to scroll though.

Comment: is that element the scollable one?

Comment: Can you provide a full small example of what doesn't work, including HTML and CSS? Could be that you are not trying to set the scrollTop on the scrolling container. if the `scrollHeight` is equal to the `clientHeight`, then this div cannot be scrolled (either not enough content or a wrong `overflow` CSS value)

Comment: The scrollHeight actually equals the clientHeight

Comment: @BadmusAdeyinka from the code it looks like what is scrolling is the div with class `message-history-content`, not `messanger-body` (I haven't properly tested). Try using `let msg = document.querySelector(".message-history-content");` instead

Comment: @BaliBalo, thanks for the response. I switched between likely classes, none worked. I actually redesigned in a totally different way from this and still had the same issue once vue updates the view but i found out when i get the scrollTop after 1 second or more using setTimeout, it actually works.

Answer (score 0):

msg.scrollTop could stay with 0 value because of at least two things.

First .messanger-body don't have defined overflow property.
Second as it is initial phase content of .messanger-body have not enough content to make scroll appear on the right side of div.

Please check those options.

Comment: I added overflow:scroll to the .messanger-body. The content of the chat box fit right in it, scrolls if i use the mouse on it but scrollTop always will return 0.